# Is it able to redirect content of remote host clipboard to local clipboard?

Tags: ssh, terminal, x11, tmux

When I doing `:%y+` in a vim session on the remote host,
I actually saved the content into remote host clipboard, right?

Is there a way that I can redirect such content of `:%y+` from remote host clipboard to my local clipboard?

PS:
I worked on a tmux-client `iterm2`, using ssh to connect to remote host.
I know how to transfer file use `scp` and `rsync`, and I can select copy the remote vim content.
But I'm really curious about how to redirect the content from remote server clipboard to local clipboard.

Comment: There's no such thing as “the remote host clipboard” unless you're doing something unusual: there's a clipboard per X server, not per machine, and you wouldn't normally be running an X server on the remote machine. But your description of where you're running Vim isn't clear. Is Vim started from the SSH session, or is it inside a Tmux session with the tmux process running on the remote host? In Vim, what does `:!echo $DISPLAY` show?

Comment: @Gilles, it shows nothing. I ssh to the remote host in my tmux, and then open a vim interface in the same screen split. By using `:%y+` on it, I got nothing to my clipboard.